# how to delete words from a text file?

Tags: python, text

I have a large text file that has on every line a word followed by a set of vectors. They are all separated by spaces. The text file looks like this:

```
movie 0.545454545455 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0454545454545 0.0454545454545 ...
film 0.571428571429 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.047619047619 0.0 0.047619047619 0.0 0.0 0.0 ...
the 0.5625 0.1875 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0625 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0625 0.0 0.0625 0.0 0.0 0.0 ...
see 0.6 0.1 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.1 0.0 0.0 0.1 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 ...
```

How can I get rid of the words from this file, but with keeping the lines as they are?

The expected result is:

```
0.545454545455 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0454545454545 0.0454545454545 ...
0.571428571429 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.047619047619 0.0 0.047619047619 0.0 0.0 0.0  ...
0.5625 0.1875 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0625 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0625 0.0 0.0625 0.0 0.0 0.0 ...
0.6 0.1 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.1 0.0 0.0 0.1 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 ...
```

Comment: Can the words be not only in the start of each line ?

Comment: no, words are located only at the start of the line.

Answer (score 1):

```
for line in text:
    (" ").join(line.split(" ")[1:])
```

Answer (score 0):

If the words can occur anywhere in the line, you can read the file, remove text and then store it back again.

```
import re

with open('largefile.txt') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

for i, line in enumerate(lines):
    lines[i] = re.sub("^[0-9+\s]", "", line) # remove everything that is not a number or space

with open('largefile.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.writelines(lines)
```

I am not sure if the regex is perfect, but when I tried it worked. Take a back up just in case.

Answer (score 0):

You could create another file by editing this one. Here is how I would do it.

```
with open('first_file.txt','w+') as myFile, open('file_two.txt','w') as writeFile:
    data = myFile.read()
    for line in data.splitlines():
        writeFile.write(''.join(line.split(' ')[1:]) + '\n')
    myFile.write(' ')
```

I'm writing back into the first file so that it becomes a Zero size file and you can save that space after.